# lwjgl 3 macOS issue with creating windows

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl, glfw

I created some code to work with lwjgl3, and ran into an issue with the macOS bindings since I am working on a mac.

The issue is that I cannot seem to get my program to create any windows. I know this for sure as the program just stops at that point. There are no errors.

The line the code gets stuck on is:

```
long window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", MemoryUtil.NULL, MemoryUtil.NULL);
```

Since I am developing on IntelliJ, whenever I disconnect the process, it crashes with :

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) 
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT 
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

I feel that that is not the issue, as I tried running another code dependant on lwjgl3, and it also got stuck at the part creating the window.

I know that the code is stuck at the part to create the window as I have put print statements every line.

I really hope that this is not a compatibility issue with either macOS Big Sur or the mac book pro 2015 model.

while `glfwInit()` return `true`, when I run `System.out.println(glGetString(GL_VERSION) );`, I get this error `Fatal error: Thread[main,5,main]: No context is current or a function that is not available in the current context was called. The JVM will abort execution.`

Here is the complete code that I am using for testing:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();


        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);


        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
// Should be true for macOS, according to GLFW docs, to get core profile.
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
// According to Apple docs, non-core profiles are limited to version 2.1.
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        // Create the window
        long window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", MemoryUtil.NULL, MemoryUtil.NULL);


        //glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


        System.out.println('0');
        
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        


    }
```

I have googled this multiple times:
cannot seem to find a relevant answer. One person suggested that macOS has a hidden popup that had to be closed for the window to be assigned, but I did everything to disable it (as I could not find it) and still nothing happened. I think the `GL_VERSION` indicates an issue with how openGL is being bound to Java.

[Edit]
Ensured that the app was running on the main thread by passing in the JVM option `-XstartOnFirstThread`.

[EDIT2]

After leaving the project for a few hours, I came back and reran it.
I added one extra line on the top:

```
System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");
```

The `createWindow(...)` function started working, which is weird as I do not know why. It also started working if I removed the line, so if anyone knows what was happening please let me know.

I am leaving the question unanswered as I still do not know the reason for the issue, I just happened to be lucky that it fixed itself.

[EDIT3]

I force rebuilt the entire project on intellij and it stopped working again. Am really confused as to why it was working in between

Comment: forgot to mention that I added the flag. 
The error says exception on Thread main

Comment: could you elaborate on how to do that? Maybe a link. I did see is somewhere but was unable to find any more information

Comment: so as far as I can tell, all the `GL. createCapabilities()` etc. happen after the  `GLFW.createWindow(...)` call. But that won't fix the issue of the fact that `createWindow` is not returning a value. I don't think this is the fix : (

Comment: As mentioned, I've searched for the hidden popup that the used suggested. I even disabled the popup, cleared the cache so that the app state isn't registered, etc. But couldn't seem to either get the app to start, or get that popup to appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the -XstartOnFirstThread on the gradle.properties. Try set it in the jvmargs of the run configuration you currently have. That fixed it for me